# I want to add camera functionality as service, but its not identifying the service

Tags: angularjs

The service factory that I am adding is not getting identified,

> ionic.bundle.js:20306 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Picture

I am new to this field, and not able to crack this problem.

```
.factory('Pictures', ['$scope', '$cordovaCamera', '$ionicLoading', '$localstorage', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera, $ionicLoading,  $localstorage){
 ..
}]
```

I want to use this factory in controller like,

```
.controller('addStoreCtrl',['$scope', '$state', '$timeout', '$stateParams','Localstorage', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$http', 'Settings', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup','Pictures',function($scope, $state, $timeout, $stateParams,Localstorage, $cordovaGeolocation, $http, Settings, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, Pictures){
```

Comment: If you're using `Pictures` factory then why does it give error for `Picture` ?

Comment: $scope can't be injected in a service. Use $rootScope instead

Comment: Thanks. yeah, I removed $scope from injection list and it worked.